# How can I establish conditions on test inputs when performing Property-based testing?

Tags: f#, fscheck, property-based-testing

How can I establish conditions on test inputs when performing Property-based testing?

For example, the following code generates bools when I need ints:

```
Gen.map (fun v -> v > 0)
```

Here's the function:

```
[<Property(QuietOnSuccess = true)>]
let ``number of cells in grid equals rowcount squared`` () =
    let values = Arb.generate<int> |> Gen.map (fun v -> v > 0) 
                                   |> Arb.fromGen
```

I need something like this so that I can get qualifying ints:

```
Gen.filter (fun v -> v > 0)
```

However, I just don't see an option for this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Dude, I'm starting to get the hang of FSharp now. I'm still not on your level though. I took a two week break from coding and now I'm back.

Comment: Of interest: [FsCheck -  generators, shrinkers and Arbitrary instances](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/TestData.html#Test-data-generators-shrinkers-and-Arbitrary-instances)

Comment: `Gen.where` or `Gen.suchThat`?

Comment: Of interest: [FsCheck - Gen](https://fscheck.github.io/FsCheck/reference/fscheck-gen.html)

Comment: Of interest: [Use FsCheck to create random dummy data](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/low-risk-ways-to-use-fsharp-at-work-3/#test-dummy)

Comment: We've now [added `Gen.filter` to FsCheck](https://github.com/fscheck/FsCheck/pull/244).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Gen.suchThat (fun v -> v > 0)`